# How to thread with tkinter in python3 using queue?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, queue

I'm trying to thread definitions in tkinter using queue in specifically python3

I've had similar code in python2 work great using a similar method without queue but in python3 from what i've read tkinter doesn't allow for multithreading with gui. I found some examples that uses Queue process. They outline i'm suppose to create an Queue object, a new thread with access to that queue and check for input in the main thread

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
import queue
import subprocess

def temp_sensor(queue_list):
    warning = 0
    while True:
        var = "cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp"
        temp_control = subprocess.check_output([var], shell=True)
        temp_length = len(temp_control)
        temp_control = temp_control[35:]
        temp_control = temp_control[:-4]
        temp_control = int(temp_control)
        degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
        displayed_temp = "Tempature: " + str(temp_control) + degree_sign + "C"

        if temp_control > 79:
            warning = warning + 1
            if warning == 3:
                print ("Warning Core Tempature HOT!")
                warning = 0

        if temp_control > 90:
                time.sleep(3)
                print ("Warning EXTREMLY to HOT!!!")

        queue_list.put(displayed_temp)            
        time.sleep(1)

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, queue_list):
        self.queue_list = queue_list
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("485x100+750+475")
        main_tempature_status = StringVar(self.root)

        Ts = Entry(self.root, textvariable=main_tempature_status)
        Ts.pack()
        Ts.place(x=331, y=70, width=160, height=25)
        Ts.config(state=DISABLED, disabledforeground="Black")

        self.root.after(1000, self.read_queue)

    def read_queue(self):
        try:
            temp = self.queue.get_nowait()
            self.main_tempature_status.set(temp)
        except queue_list.Empty:
            pass

        self.root.after(1000, self.read_queue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_list = queue.Queue()

    gui = Gui(queue_list)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=temp_sensor, args=(queue_list,))
    t1.start()

    gui.root.mainloop()
```

My desired result is to run a some of these definitions to do various tasks and display their variables in the tkinter entry using python3.
when i run my code it gives me the variable from the queue but it won't post to the GUI. please forgive my less then pythonic code.

Comment: Try changing `gui.root.mainloop` to `gui.root.mainloop()`.

Comment: good catch thank you the gui does load now. but with that change and my own to the def read_queue(self):.. i get the variable through the queue but i can get it to post to the gui now

Comment: Change `main_tempature_status` to `self.main_tempature_status` in `Gui.__init__()` .  Also change `self.queue.get_nowait()` to `self.queue_list.get_nowait()` and `queue_list.Empty` to `queue.Empty` in `Gui.read_queue()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `Gui` class to this:

```
class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, queue_list):
        self.queue_list = queue_list
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("485x100+750+475")
        self.main_tempature_status = StringVar(self.root)

        self.Ts = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.main_tempature_status)
        self.Ts.pack()
        self.Ts.place(x=331, y=70, width=160, height=25)
        self.Ts.config(state=DISABLED, disabledforeground="Black")

        self.root.after(1000, self.read_queue)

    def read_queue(self):
        try:
            temp = self.queue_list.get_nowait()
            self.Ts.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.main_tempature_status.set(temp)
            self.Ts.config(state=DISABLED)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        self.root.after(1000, self.read_queue)
```

**Explanation**:

1. variable `main_temperature_status` is used in function `read_queue` as class variable, but not defined as class variable.
2. You cannot show the change in value of `Entry` widget if it is always disabled, so enabling it before value change in `read_queue`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and help the code works as desired. Very appreciated.